# CORS issue with web API

Tags: .net, visual-studio, iis, asp.net-web-api, cors

I am facing CORS issue in API. Getting following response:

```
> {"$id":"1","Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS'."}
```

Settings done in web.config to allow 'OPTIONS' method. But still not working. Below are my web.config settings.

```
`<system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
`
```